# Schengen visa with one entry

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration

I have a Schengen visa with one entry, and I have entered Schengen from Frankfurt and then all the way to Norway. After that I will be passing by Amsterdam to visit friends via Frankfurt airport, will that be eligible?

And a single entry means entering only one country in Schengen, or only one entry to Schengen and if I exit Schengen I can't reenter.

Answer (score 1):

> I will be passing by Amsterdam to visit friends via Frankfurt airport, will that be eligible?

The Schengen Area counts as a single country for border purposes (hence the common visa), meaning that, unless you hold an LTV visa (which is an exceptional thing), you're free to move within the entire area while the visa is valid.

So yes, you can go to Amsterdam.

> And a single entry means entering only one country in Schengen, or only one entry to Schengen and if I exit Schengen I can't reenter.

It means you can only enter the Schengen Area once - once you exit you need a new visa to re-enter

When going from Oslo to Frankfurt, you'll depart from the international section, but without passport control, because Norway is in Schengen. The "single country" is Schengen, **not** the EU

Comment: What is an LTV visa, and how would someone who has a Schengen visa know whether he or she has one?

Comment: @phoog A 'limited territorial validity' visa is issued for only one or some of the Schengen states and not for the entire Schengen area. The Schengen visa has a field 'valid for', which either indicates 'Schengen states' for a regular visa (all states) or a list of countries on an LTV visa.